# Calling Argument in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that demands a -p argument when calling. However, how do I call the -p argument in the SQL query? I am also looking to use this -p argument text in the output file name.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import psycopg2
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='insert the project ID as an 
argument')
parser.add_argument('-p','--project_id', help='project_id to pull files from 
ERAPRO',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="XXX", user="XXX", password="XXX", 
host="XXX", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT project_analysis.project_accession, 
analysis.analysis_accession, file.filename, file.file_md5, file.file_location
    FROM project_analysis
    LEFT JOIN analysis on project_analysis.analysis_accession = analysis.analysis_accession
    LEFT JOIN analysis_file on analysis.analysis_accession = analysis_file.analysis_accession
    LEFT JOIN file on analysis_file.file_id = file.file_id
    WHERE project_accession = <INSERT -p ARGUMENT HERE> and analysis.hidden_in_eva = '0';""")

records = cur.fetchall()

with open ('/nfs/production3/eva/user/gary/evapro_ftp/<INSERT -p ARGUMENT 
HERE>.csv', 'w') as f:
writer = csv.writer (f, delimiter = ',')
for row in records:
    writer.writerow(row)

conn.close()
```

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First assign your argument to variable using `dest` argument to `add_argument()`. lets say we assign the input to the project_id variable.
This way we can reference it in the code.

```
parser.add_argument('-p','--project_id', 
                     help='project_id to pull files from
                     ERAPRO',
                     required=True,
                     dest='project_id') # notice the dest argument

cur.execute("""SELECT project_analysis.project_accession, 
analysis.analysis_accession, file.filename, file.file_md5, file.file_location
    FROM project_analysis
    LEFT JOIN analysis on project_analysis.analysis_accession = analysis.analysis_accession
    LEFT JOIN analysis_file on analysis.analysis_accession = analysis_file.analysis_accession
    LEFT JOIN file on analysis_file.file_id = file.file_id
    WHERE project_accession = %s and analysis.hidden_in_eva = '0';""", (args.project_id))
```

Notice the use of `execute(' ... %s ...', (args.project_id))` by doing this we interpolated the value referenced by `project_id` into the string.

Comment: I suppose you wanted `(args.project_id)` instead of `(project_id)` as parameter to `execute` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After calling `args = parser.parse_args()` you can obtain the value of the arguments like this:

`pid = args.project_id`

Then you can use that value of `pid` in your code by using normal string substitution. However, it's better to use psycopg2's inbuilt method for passing parameters to SQL queries to prevent SQL injection.

Normal string substitution:

```
'hello world {]'.format(var_name)
```

psycopg2:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * from %s', (var_name))
```